# Forming an array out of maximum value of one part of the two dimensional arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, max, min

So, i have a two dimensional arrays like this :

```
double[,] tabel_nilai = new double[,]{{3500, 70, 10, 80, 3000, 36},
                                      {4500, 90, 10, 60, 2500, 48 },
                                      {4000, 80, 9, 90, 2000, 48 },
                                      {4000, 70, 8, 50, 1500, 60 }};
```

and then, I want to form one dimensional array with the maximum value on the first column (3500, 4500, 4000 and 4000). But, minimum value on the other column.

I did this :

```
double[] pembagi = new double[kepentingan.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < produk.Length; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j < kriteria.Length; i++)
    {
        pembagi[i] = Math.Max(tabel_nilai[i,j],tabel_nilai[i,j]);

        Console.WriteLine(pembagi);
    }
}
```

but, failed miserably.

I would be very pleased if somebody can give me some logics on how to solve this problem. thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "column". A one-dimensional array has one direction. If you have `var array = { 3500, 4500, 4000, 4000 }` there is no "other column" for the minimum values. You'd need a 2-dimensional array. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: @itsme86 I think he's referring to the two dimensional array when talking about columns

Comment: So your result would be an array like {max_0, min_1, max_2, ....} where max/min_i is the max/min of column i of the two dimensional array

Comment: Which other column do you mean to examine for minimum... and can you clarify what a column is.  And what is "miserable failed" actually means - failed how?

Comment: @dcg How then are you interpretting "I want to form one dimensional array with the maximum value on the first column (3500, 4500, 4000 and 4000). But, minimum value on the other column."? Maybe you can reword the desired finished product.

Comment: Well, for one thing, your max function `Math.Max(tabel_nilai[i,j],tabel_nilai[i,j])` compares the same two numbers, the second param probably should have `+1` either on `i` or `j`, but also you would need to do boundary checking.

Comment: @itsme86  (3500, 4500, 4000 and 4000) is the first column of the two dimensional array

Comment: @dcg What does that have to do with forming a one dimensional array though?

Comment: @LB2 Not to mention that OP has `i++` instead of `j++` in the inner for loop.

Comment: @itsme86, yes I saw that later too... there are quite a few issues.  Posted the corrected algorithm as answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you can use [jagged arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) to get "slice" or row of rows.

Then using [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/delegate) you can apply function as per requirement, example below:

```
delegate double maxMin(IEnumerable<double> arr);
public static void GetData()
{
            double[][] tableData = new double[][]{
                                    new double[] {3500, 70, 10, 80, 3000, 36},
                                    new double[] {4500, 90, 10, 60, 2500, 48 },
                                    new double[] {4000, 80, 9, 90, 2000, 48 },
                                    new double[] {4000, 70, 8, 50, 1500, 60 }
                                  };

            int length = tableData.Length;
            double[] requiredValues = new double[length];

            maxMin maxMinObj;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    maxMinObj = x => x.Max();
                else
                    maxMinObj = x => x.Min();

                requiredValues[i] = maxMinObj(tableData[i]);

                Console.WriteLine(requiredValues[i]);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ in this case that probably gives the shortest and simplest code to solve this without explicit use of any nested loops.

```
double[,] tabel_nilai = new double[,]{   {3500, 70, 10, 80, 3000, 36},
                                         {4500, 90, 10, 60, 2500, 48 },
                                         {4000, 80, 9, 90, 2000, 48 },
                                         {4000, 70, 8, 50, 1500, 60 }};

 double[] oneDimensionalArray = tabel_nilai.Cast<double>().Select((x, i) => new { x, index = i / tabel_nilai.GetLength(1) })  
                                        .GroupBy(x=>x.index)                                   
                                        .Select(x=>x.Select(s=>s.x).ToList().Max())                  
                                        .ToArray();
```

What it does is that it converts the 2D array into a list and then groups by each row and finally calculates Max value for that row. You can use it to get Min as well, just replace `Max()` with `Min()`. Additionally, it can help you do many other measures if you need using the same expression.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming alternating max/min for each column here is the correction to your code.  Your code had multiple issues, so I'll just post the code with all the corrections:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double[,] tabel_nilai = new double[,]{   {3500, 70, 10, 80, 3000, 36},
                                                    {4500, 90, 10, 60, 2500, 48 },
                                                    {4000, 80, 9, 90, 2000, 48 },
                                                    {4000, 70, 8, 50, 1500, 60 }};  

        for (int j = tabel_nilai.GetLowerBound(1); j <= tabel_nilai.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
        {
            var seekingMax = ((j - tabel_nilai.GetLowerBound(1)) % 2) == 0;
            var maxmin = tabel_nilai[0, j];

            for(int i = tabel_nilai.GetLowerBound(0) + 1; i <= tabel_nilai.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            {
                if (seekingMax)
                {
                    maxmin = Math.Max(maxmin,tabel_nilai[i, j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    maxmin = Math.Min(maxmin,tabel_nilai[i, j]);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", seekingMax ? "Max" : "Min", maxmin);
        }
    }
}
```